# Running Entity Code First Migrations on App_Start on SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

i've recently begun trying to move a large production database that is backed by Entity Framework Code First Migrations (EF 5). I am using code first migrations with Auto migrations turned `off`

The data layer is being upgraded inside `Application_Start()` using something along the following lines:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>(null));
using (var ctx = new MyDbContext()){
    ctx.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

After migrating the database using the "Deploy to SQL Azure" option in SQL Management studio and then pointing my app at it I've become stuck in a death spin with the following error:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

This is a lie! (or the wrong error for the job) :-)

After setting up firewall rules to allow my local Visual Studio instance to connect and then running `update-database -verbose -script` I end up with a blank result.

```
PM> update-database -verbose -script
Using StartUp project 'MyProject.Website'.
Using NuGet project 'MyProject.Data'.
Target database is: 'MyNewSQLAzureDB' (DataSource: tcp:xxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending explicit migrations.
```

i'm beginning to go mad.

things i've tried:

- Using the [SQL Azure SQL Provider](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/936)
- Doing a schema comparison between my local database backup and the Azure one (no change in table structures, although I assume indexes have changed).
- Upgrading to EF 6 incase there was a difference in the model meta data comparison going on in the old model.
- Doing the migration on `application_start()` a few different ways.

I'm thinking that this might be a bug, as my app was working with the same codebase for over 2 years before the move, and the exception seems odd for what the issue is.

What I think might be happening:

- The SQL Azure Migration tool changed some small things in my my model (adding clustered indexes to everything.
- The schema comparison part of the EF DBMigrator is seeing these changes as a difference in schema, but instead of throwing a `DbEntityValidationException` it's instead throwing a `AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException` with no model differences listed in the exception data.

Anyone have any ideas? Is there a way to take a capture of the new model and update the `_migrationhistory` table manually to make the world a happy place again?

Comment: Did you try "Add-Migration -m "foo" to see the differences?

Comment: I did. If you read my response you can see that the powershell doesn't see any difference between the DB and the model.

Comment: I had problems with EntityFramework 6.0.1 ... I rolled back to "6.0.0-rc1" using the following command: Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.0.0-rc1 -Pre and it works again. It may sound strange, but I would try that too.

Comment: First, updating a production database in this way is a bit dangerous and I wouldn't recommend it. That aside it could be that the __MigrationHistory table has not been correctly deployed to the Azure database so check that the schema and content are the same as locally. If this is not the case then I would recommend using the EdmxWriter class to get a model running locally and one running against SQL Azure. If they are different that should provide a clue.

Comment: Are you suggesting that people shouldn't move code first migrations to Azure SQL? or that people should mod the __MigrationHistory table. i've done a sql data compare and sql schema compare. both are identical in visual studio (haven't tried sql compare yet).

Comment: SQL Azure and regular SQL Server behave differently in quite a few ways and sometimes EF will generate different schemas for SQL Azure than it does for SQL Server because of this.But my suggestions were ideas for how to figure out what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual cause of this was a missing dependency in my data layer.

My entity framework domain POCO's had Json.Net attributes on some properties.

As attributes are run using reflection, and fail silently, the exception being thrown has nothing to do with the end result.

As Alex mentions in his response, I blogged about the journey to solving this here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2013/12/05/sorrow-and-elation-ndash-why-reflection-isnt-always-your-friend

As he says in his comment, the way to troubleshoot this would have been to turn Fusion Logging on. Sadly at the time the constant `AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException` kept making me search in a completely different place.

The moral of the story may be: When hitting dead ends in your search for a problem, add fusion logging as a run through step.

Comment: Q: Were you troubleshooting this issue in Azure? And, if so, was it a web role? And, if so, were you able to find fuslogvw.exe on the server, or did you install it yourself somehow?

Answer (score 2):

`AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException` is definitely misleading here.

I believe this post might help you solve the problem. http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2013/12/05/sorrow-and-elation-ndash-why-reflection-isnt-always-your-friend.

Recommendation is to run fuslogvw ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) on the server to find out which assembly your website is having difficulty finding.

It's probably just a matter of getting your nuget packages in sync.

Comment: Hi Alex - thanks for the link. Interestingly enough this was actually my blog post on finding the solution :-)